# creating tcl list of first 2 column of matrix

Tags: tcl

I have matrix of 10 rows and 10 column. I want to crate tcl list where each element of list will be 2 numbers..1 from each row.
    e.g if My matrix is

```
$a $b $c $d $e  
$f $g $h $i $j  
$k $l $m $n $o  
$p $q $r $s $t
```

I want to have list that contain elements `$a $b`, `$f $g`, `$k $l`, `$p $q`.
Can someone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Have you created a Tcl list before? It sounds like what you want is a list containing lists. This is possible. But what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your matrix is a list of lists, you can use [the `lmap` command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lmap.htm):

```
$ tclsh
% set matrix {
{a b c d e}
{f g h i j}
{k l m n o}
{p q r s t}
}

{a b c d e}
{f g h i j}
{k l m n o}
{p q r s t}

% lmap sublist $matrix {lrange $sublist 0 1}
{a b} {f g} {k l} {p q}
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, I have tcl8.4. so lmap is not supported.

Comment: Copy the second code snippet from this page: https://wiki.tcl.tk/40570. Put it in your program and you have `lmap`. Also, upgrade if possible, Tcl 8.4 is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a matrix as defined by the [`struct::matrix` package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/matrix.html) in Tcllib, you do this:

```
set pairlist [$matrix get rect  0 0  1 end]
```

Notes: the name of the matrix is in the `matrix` variable, `rect` is short for “rectangle”, the `0 0` give the coordinates in the matrix of the top-left corner of the rectangle to extract, and `1 end` gives the coordinates in the matrix of the bottom right corner of the rectangle (matrices support `end` to mean the last row and/or column, just like Tcl strings and lists).

Answer (score 0):

```
package require struct::matrix 

struct::matrix data
data add columns 5
data add rows    4

data set rect 0 0 {
{a b c d e}
{f g h i j}
{k l m n o}
{p q r s t}
}

data get rect 0 0 1 end
# {a b} {f g} {k l} {p q}
```

This should produce the results